# reading a reactive (live) HTML webcam pixels output without storing the display ( R and or Shiny)

Tags: html, r, rstudio, shiny

I am fairly stackoverflow and am currently working on a prototype which involves having to process a webcam video to do further "live" analysis.
In my shiny app folder I have a webcam.html file which is used to activate the webcam on Chrome depicted below:

```html
<video autoplay id="webcam" width="300" height="300" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:100;cursor:move;" draggable="false"></video>

<script>
// for Google Chrome only; if you use other web browsers,
// you need to change webkit to other names; see
// http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function(stream) {
  var video = document.getElementById('webcam');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, function(e) {});

// make the video draggable
(function() {
  function drag_start(event) {
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
      (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("right"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
  }
  function drag_over(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
  function drop(event) {
      var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
      dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
      dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
  var dm = document.getElementById('webcam');
  dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false);
  document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false);
  document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false);
})();
</script>
```

UI Code:

```css
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)
library(EBImage)
library(webshot)


shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  skin = ("black"),
  dashboardHeader(title= "Visual I-Ad Solution"),
     
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Output-Visualization", tabName = "about1", icon = icon("info"))
    )),
    
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "about1",  
                htmlOutput("inc"),
                box(
                  title = "Reactive Image Processor",status="info",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = TRUE,
                  textOutput("text") 
                  )
        )))
))
```

Server Code:

```css
# This is the server logic for a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)
library(EBImage)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("webcam.html"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})

  output$text<-renderPrint(
  print(readImage(webshot("https://www.r-project.org/", "r-viewport.png", cliprect = "viewport")))
  
  ) 
})
```

As depicted in the Server code, my goal is to be able to read the webcam images on a live/reactive environment in shiny (chrome) in the information box in order to be able to run image/video "live" processing.

I saved the App Screenshot link in wordpress since I am not yet allowed to post images on stackoverflow

Screenshot link:
https://brianmajablog.wordpress.com/2017/05/28/a-screenshot-link-to-the-stackoverflow-question/

Comment: tracking.js might have an answer to this. Will look at it and see if i can get to the solution.